# Font Awesome Icons Showing As Slanted "Hamburger Menus" on WordPress Site

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, font-awesome

This seems to be a different issue from 'font awesome icons not showing' or 'font awesome icons showing up as empty boxes'. Because in this case, the font awesome icons almost appear as slanted hamburger menus, with five lines each:

[image]

I've loaded Font Awesome and Bootstrap in my `functions.php` file like this (this is a WordPress theme):

```
<?php

function custom_theme_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
    wp_enqueue_style('cancom-bootstrap', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
    wp_enqueue_style('cancom-fontawesome', 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css', array(), '1.0', 'all');
}
 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_theme_assets');
```

And I'm inserting the icons in my `header.php` file like this:

```
<div class="top-header-left">
   <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
   <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
   <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
</div>
```

Just as FontAwesome says to do [in their docs](https://fontawesome.com/icons/instagram?style=brands)

Does anyone know why the icons are showing up this way?

Here is the live site:

https://cancom.drawyourpets.com/

I'm not seeing any errors in the console or network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using font awesome 4.7.0. Upgrade it to version 5.x or use the proper syntax for your version

https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/instagram

```
<div class="top-header-left">
   <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
</div>
```